# How do i automatically deploy a mean stack application on to AWS server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, bitbucket, web-deployment, mean-stack

I have a mean stack application running on an AWS instance, but whenever there is a commit, we have to manually deploy the code by using putty and winSCP,

Is there a way to detect changes in the Bitbucket(we use BB as it has private repos) repository and automatically push the changes to the AWS instance?

i heard gulp can do the task , but i doubt it can push code to the instance.

can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move your application to Elastic Beanstalk. You could use Amazon Code Deploy (although I don't think it works with Bitbucket yet). You could setup a Jenkins server that would do this for you. You could use Gulp to do this, or countless other similar tools. There are also services like DeployHQ and Codeship that will do this for you.

Comment: i did try using jenkins, it did not recognize bitbucket repo, it did detect github ones, strange as bitbucket also uses git internally

Comment: but can that deploy code to AWS? it says it a task runner/ builder